# C# listbox item identification

Tags: c#, if-statement, listbox, selecteditem

Keep in mind, i am not very experienced with c#.

I am coding a remove button for a list box and the basic function of removing the selected item works.

```
listBoxSum.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxSum.SelectedIndex);
```

I'm trying to make an IF statement which will allow me to select an item from my list-box and have it identify the text inside of it (Most likely a string).

As i don't know too much about c#, this is what i currently have for the if statement (obviously the first line is error).

```
if (listBoxSum.SelectedItem = "Tea")
        {
            totalCost = totalCost - teaCost;
            txtBox_Amount.Text = totalCost.ToString();
        }
```

I have tried making other strings to help simplify the statement like (*Below is not the main piece of code for the if statement, the above code is. This was just an experiment on try and extend the code to make it a bit more understandable for myself*):

```
       string teaSelect = "Tea" + teaCost;
       string selection = (string) listBoxSum.SelectedItem;

       if (selection == teaSelect)
       {
            totalCost = totalCost - teaCost;
            txtBox_Amount.Text = totalCost.ToString();
       }
```

Please help, i don't know whether i should change how i'm thinking about this or if it an easy fix hiding in plain sight. Personally i have been stumped on this little button for around 2 hours figuring out how i am going to make the remove button work with the calculations.

Comment: How do you fill the List?

Comment: The List controls can literally store *anything* so rather than text (I guess), if it stored a concrete type which included a name and cost, it would be easier to keep the data together.  A `List<T>` as a datasource would be the best move

Comment: `if (listBoxSum.SelectedItem = "Tea"` should have 2 `==` signs. Not sure if that is a typo. Also, you need to tell us in plain English what your code is supposed to do so we can help.

Comment: @Grantly on my main form, i have buttons which you select i.e Tea, Latte, Hot chocolate etc. From this the listbox begins to fill up, code of this is:

// Set cost
teaCost = 3.50m;

//Show amount into total amount
totalCost = totalCost + teaCost;
txtBox_Amount.Text = totalCost.ToString();

Comment: We need to know what objects you fill your list with...By default, the Item.ToString() method is used to show what you see in the Lists, but you may have to override this to gain more control.  Try ToString() in your problem area in your question, but its not a 'proper' solution unless you control the method ToString()

Comment: @Grantly listBoxSum.Items.Add("Tea       " + teaCost); 
this is what is used to fill the list, i put in the wrong section before hand

Comment: You seem to be missing a space character here : teaSelect = "Tea" + teaCost;

Comment: @Grantly I think i havent clarified the statements enough, the first bit of code is what i currently have, and what i am focusing on. The second bit was really just the same thing but i was just trying to find what may work

Comment: @CodingYoshi the beggining statement of 
If (listBoxSum.SelectedItem == "Tea") 
is meant to see if the selected item name is equal to the text "tea", if it isnt then an else if would go onto the next beverage. until the item selected is identified and removed with the assigned item cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not updating your item that holds the "Tea + cost" value, you should probably identify it either by string.StartsWith or maybe assigning it with an identifier of your choice. This could be an integer, an enum or another concrete class with predefined instances.

You can do this by using the Tag property for WPF and creating a simple class for Windows Forms ([WPF Tag Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Tag)).

A simple example for Windows Forms would be:

```
enum FoodType
{
    Tea = 2
}
class FoodItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public FoodType FoodType { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

When you are adding your items:

```
listBoxSum.Items.Add(new FoodItem
{
    FoodType = FoodType.Tea,
    Text = "Tea " + teaCost
});
```

And when you are filtering them:

```
if (listBoxSum.SelectedItem is FoodItem foodItem && foodItem.FoodType == FoodType.Tea)
{
    // Do work
}
```

It is even easier for WPF:

```
enum FoodType
{
    Tea = 1
}
```

Adding items:

```
listBoxSum.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem
{
    Content = "Tea " + teaCost,
    Tag = FoodType.Tea
});
```

Identifying items:

```
if (listBoxSum.SelectedItem is ListBoxItem foodItem && foodItem.Tag is FoodType foodType && foodType == FoodType.Tea)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to check is whether the item you are currently looking at is a ListBoxItem, and if so, is the contained content a text and is this text equal to your desired text, in order to identify the correct item.

```
var content = (((x.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem)?.Content as string);
if (content != null && content == "MyDesiredText") {...}
```

This would be a valid, but not an elegant solution.
A better way would be to remember the listbox items while creating them

```
var desiredListBoxItem = new ListBoxItem(...)
x.AddChild(desiredListBoxItem);
```

and afterwards, check whether the object references match:

```
if (x.SelectedItem == desiredListBoxItem) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your item in `ListBox` is called "Tea"?If it is your if statement should look something like this:

```
if(yourTextBox.Items[yourTextBox.SelectedIndex] == "Tea")
{
    //Your Code
}
```